# Global variable x is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.3

Now here is my issue, this is my code located below. This program finds the roots of a number of the users choice. My issue is when I run this code I get, `NameError: global name 'x' is not defined`. It is coming from the `main` function when the value `x` is first encountered. I assume the same will happen to all of the other value's so basically what I am wondering is will I have to define these values outside of the `ValueGrabber` function? Or can I keep it how it is and just change it a bit?

```
def ValueGraber():
    x = input("What number do you want to find the root of?:  ")
    root = input("Which root do you want to find?:  ")
    epsilon = input("What accuracy do you want the value to be to? e.g 0.01 :  ")
    high = float(x) + 1
    low = 0.0
    ans = (high + low)/2.0
    Perfect = None
    return x, root, epsilon, ans, high, low, Perfect

def RootFinder(x, root, epsilon, ans, high, low):
    while (ans**float(root)-float(x)) > epsilon and ans != float(x):
        if ans**float(root) > float(x):
        ans = high
        else:
        ans = high
            ans = (high + low)/2.0
    return ans

def PerfectChecker(ans, x, root, Perfect):
    if round(ans, 1)**float(root) == x:
        Perfect = True
    else:
        Perfect = False
    return Perfect

def Output(ans, x, root, perfect, epsilon):
    if Perfect == True:
        print("The number {0} has a perfect {1} root of    {2}".format(float(x),float(root),float(ans)))
    else:
        print("The root of the number {0} has a {1} root of {2} to an accuracy of {3}".format(float(x),float(root),float(ans),float(epsilon)))

def main():
    InputData = ValueGraber()
    DataOpp = RootFinder(x, root, epsilon, ans, high, low)
    PCheck = PerfectChecker(ans, x, root, Perfect)
    DataOutput = Output(ans, x, root, Perfect, epsilon)

main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `main` you refer to `x` but never defined it.

Your `ValueGraber()` function does return a value `x` but that name is not then automatically available to the caller.

The names in the `main()` function are *local*; they don't automatically reflect the names returned from the functions in any case. Here is a fixed `main` function that just *happens* to use the same names as the functions for returned values:

```
def main():    
    x, root, epsilon, ans, high, low, PerfecutData = ValueGraber()
    ans = RootFinder(x, root, epsilon, ans, high, low)
    Perfect = PerfectChecker(ans, x, root, Perfect)
    Output(ans, x, root, Perfect, epsilon)
```

I removed `DateOutput`; it'll always be `None` because `Output()` doesn't return anything.

You can still use *different* names in `main`; `DataOpp` is a perfectly valid local name (even though I personally would use `lower_case_with_underscores` style for local names, always), but you then should not expect `ans` to exist, you'd use `DataOpp` everywhere in `main` instead.